# hydra - structured config group/package override via yaml

Tags: fb-hydra

I'm not very successfully trying to figure out how to achieve an override of a group/package with and via a yaml file.  Trying to explain my problem using the example (files and folder structre) from the hydra documentation https://hydra.cc/docs/tutorials/structured_config/schema/.

yaml.config as:

```
defaults:
  - base_config                 # --> reference to dataclass
  - db: base_mysql              # --> reference to dataclass
  - _self_ debug: true
```

gives the expected (print when running the myapp.py):

```
db:
  driver: mysql
  host: localhost
  port: 3306
  user: ???
  password: ???
```

Using the yaml file instead instead of the base_mysql dataclass is also fine thus the yaml.config as:

```
defaults:
  - base_config
  - db: mysql                   # --> reads db/mysql.yaml
  - _self_
debug: true
```

prints again as expected

```
db:
  driver: mysql
  host: localhost
  port: 3306
  user: omry
  password: secret
```

Overriding individual fields is as well fine, e.g. with config.yaml like

```
defaults:
  - base_config
  - db: mysql
  - _self_
debug: true
db:
  password: UpdatedPassword
```

What I'm to able to figure out is how to override the full db group with a/via another yaml file - defining the structure via a dataclass and then override/set the values like:

```
defaults:
  - base_config
  - db: base_mysql      # --> reference to dataclass to define the structure
  - _self_
debug: true
db: mysql        # --> mysql.yaml
```

throws the following error:
In 'config': Validation error while composing config:

```
Merge error: str is not a subclass of MySQLConfig. value: mysql
    full_key: 
    object_type=Config
```

Searching the internet/stackoverflow already showed me that moving the *self* to the first position will get rid of the error - but then the composition order is "wrong".

Keeping the order as it is and using the mysql.yaml for an override works well - when done via commandline (python myapp.py db=mysql when the line "db:mysql" is not present), but for my usecase it much more convinient to handle it all via the yaml file(s).

Somehow I assume that the same functionality is available via CLI and files/code and that I just did not mange to figure out how it works.

(hydra version 1.1 in a conda environment with python 3.9)

Thank you very much in advance for any help that you can provide.

Answer (score 0):

If understand correctly, you want to use the defaults list in your primary yaml file to merge together the `base_mysql` config with the `mysql` config. This will do the trick:

```yaml
defaults:
  - base_config
  - db: [base_mysql, mysql]
  - _self_
debug: true
```

Passing a list `[base_mysql, mysql]` of config names causes those configs `base_mysql` and `mysql` to be merged together. This is documented [here](https://hydra.cc/docs/advanced/defaults_list/#introduction) -- see the "`CONFIG_NAMES`" alternative for specifying an option in the defaults list.

Note that passing the CLI override `db=mysql` (as in `python myapp.py db=mysql`) results in modification of the defaults list; the resulting defaults list will be the same as if you had used the following in your yaml file:

```yaml
defaults:
  - base_config
  - db: mysql
  - _self_
debug: true
```

You can pass a list `[base_mysql, mysql]` of config names at the CLI like this:

```
python my_app.py 'db=[base_mysql, mysql]'
```

Comment: Hi Jasha, thank you very much for your answer, though it seems to me that it does not solve my problem. What I want to achieve is the same behavior as the CLI override "python myapp.py db=mysql" when the defaults lists of the config contains the line " -db: base_mysql" but via the yaml file. Usecase like: define params via the dataclass and use this in defaults list to define the structure. Wanting to work e.g. with different mysql databases so create for each a yaml file and reference to the needed one via override. Don't know if that makes my question any more understandable.

Comment: I see. Have you seen the Hydra docs on [configuring experiments](https://hydra.cc/docs/patterns/configuring_experiments/)? If you want to use a different yaml file to change the setting for `db`, you'll probably need to use the "override" keyword and put `db: new_setting` in the defaults list of the second yaml file. Feel free to open a Q&A thread at https://github.com/facebookresearch/hydra/discussions .